# Gridlayout formatting in kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy

I am currently working on a app in kivy. I have a question for gridlayout and buttons. This is how my buttons and pictures looks like now https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrbkL.png. When u see the picture u will see a playbutton and next to the playbutton I want to add two more pictures. Can anybody help

This is my code for the picture

```
GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        size_hint: 1, 1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, .4
            pos_hint: {"top": .4, "right": 1}
            text: "This is player 1"
        ImageButton:
            size_hint: 1, .2
            pos_hint: {"top": .2, "right": 1}
            source: "play.png"
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, .4
            pos_hint: {"top": .4, "right": 1}
            text: "This the second player"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to insert another GridLayout with 3 columns in the second row, so something like this:

```
GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        size_hint: 1, 1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "right": 1}
        Button:
            size_hint: 1, .4
            pos_hint: {"top": .4, "right": 1}
            text: "This is player 1"

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3

            ImageButton:
                size_hint: 1, .2
                pos_hint: {"top": .2, "right": 1}
                source: "play.png"
            ImageButton:
                size_hint: 1, .2
                pos_hint: {"top": .2, "right": 1}
                source: "play.png"
            ImageButton:
                size_hint: 1, .2
                pos_hint: {"top": .2, "right": 1}
                source: "play.png"

        Button:
            size_hint: 1, .4
            pos_hint: {"top": .4, "right": 1}
            text: "This the second player"
```